# Angular - Issue on navigating from one sibling to another lazy loaded component with a parent with path parameters

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm using angular 9 and I'm using Lazy-loading feature modules. I'm not able to navigate from one component to the sibling one. I have the following structure:

**src/app/app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module1.module').then(m => m.Module1Module)
  },
  {
    path: 'module2/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module2.module').then(m => m.Module2Module)
  }
];
```

**src/app/app.component.html**

```
<button routerLink="/module1">Go to Module1</button>
<button routerLink="/module2/MyId">Go to Module1</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**src/app/module2/module2-routing.module.ts | similar rc/app/module1/module1-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Module2Component,
    children: [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'child1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'child1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./child1.module').then(m => m.Child1Module)
  },
  {
    path: 'child2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./child2.module').then(m => m.Child2Module)
  }
  ]
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Module1RoutingModule { }
```

**src/app/module2/child1/child1.component.html**

```
<button routerLink="../child2">Go to Module2/MyId/child2</button>
```

My problem is that from home to module1 I have the correct url, i.e. http://localhost:4200/module1 but if I would like to module2/MyID/child2 from module2/MyID/child1 then it goes to http://localhost:4200/module2/MyID/child1/child2 instead of http://localhost:4200/module2/MyID/child2

Thanks

Comment: You want to pass queryParams while navigating to module2?

Comment: I'm passing path parameter and then from child1 I want to go to child2 but keeping the parameter I had

Comment: <a [routerLink]="['/module2']"  [queryParams]="{title: ti, param2: true}" >Go to Module2</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case somebody has the same issue, the solution I found is to use absolute path and getting the Path Params from activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute. So I have:

**src/app/module2/child1/child1.module.ts**

```
baseUrl = '/module2/{id}';
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
ngOnInit() {
    this.baseUrl = this.baseUrl.replace('{id}', this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id);
}
```

**src/app/module2/child1/child1.component.html**

```
<button routerLink="{{baseUrl}}/child2">Go to Module2/MyId/child2</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `routerLink="/module2"`.

Comment: Hi...you're right...I'm going to rephrase my question because I was trying to simplify it.